# What is the "-" at the end of some files?

Tags: files, etc

I find a lot of the time that files in `/etc` end with a `-`, but have another version of the file without it at the end. So what does the `-` mean? Is it like a `~`? Or does it serve a different purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ls /etc/*-
/etc/group-    /etc/passwd-  /etc/subgid-
/etc/gshadow-  /etc/shadow-  /etc/subuid-
```

These are just backup files. For example `/etc/passwd` has its backup file with name `/etc/passwd-` and so on.

When programs like `useradd`, `usermod` etc. (who has to edit those files) edits them keep a backup copy with `-` appended at the end.

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27746/52402)

Comment: Do you know why sometimes a backed up file is denoted with a `-` and sometimes with a `~`? Is it something like, if system file backup use `-`, otherwise use `~`? I have noticed that when I work with certain text editors they back up the files by appending a `~` at the end of them.